# Is it possible (or sane) to use an alternate dependency style for tomcat application deploys?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

We have an application that apparently has a lot of dependencies. It's a 150MB WAR file when packaged with all the dependencies. However, our application code only accounts for about 8MB of this.

In the idea of trimming the time it takes to do a redeploy I was thinking that potentially we could have a "dependencies" something or another (I'm not terribly familiar with Java) that is a 142 MB WAR, and then our application that's actually just the 8MB and then we only have to redeploy that.

Is this possible? If so, is it recommended? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy all the external generic jars in the lib folder of your tomcat so it will be available for all the applications deployed there, then deploy your war in the webapps folder as you're currently doing. Since looks that this war is the only application that will interact with these libraries, then there should be no problem.

```
<tomcat-home>
- lib
  + commonJar1.jar
  + commonJar2.jar
  + commonJar3.jar
  + ...
- webapps
  + yourApp.war
```